# ReactiveExtensions and Asynchronous Service Methods?

Tags: c#, wcf, task, .net-4.5, system.reactive

I'm having trouble (probably trouble understanding) with ReactiveExtensions, I have a WCF service I connect to in a WinForms application, and from following tutorials this Is what I've come up with, and this was never working so I changed it from the regular synchronous methods to the asynchronous ones, I started to syntax errors instead. Why does `Task<T[]>.ToObservable()` give me a `T[]` when I subscribe to it? I may have a lot more than that wrong. Thanks for any help!

```
        var users =
            _chatServiceClient.GetAllUsersAsync()
                .ToObservable()
                .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
                .ObserveOn(this)
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                .DistinctUntilChanged();

        var messages =
            _chatServiceClient.GetNewMessagesAsync(_me)
                .ToObservable()
                .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
                .ObserveOn(this)
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
                .Subscribe(m => chatRichTextBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}:{1}: {2}", m.Date, m.User, m.Content)));

        userList.DataSource = users;
```

Comment: `Why does Task<T[]>.ToObservable() give me a T[] when I subscribe to it?`  Because the result of a `Task<T[]>` is `T[]` ?

Comment: @McGarnagle Yes, but when I subscribe to the non async version, I get a `T` instead.

Comment: @TristanMcPherson You're gonna need to show an example of the non-async version before we can tell you why they're different. If you mean `T[].ToObservable()`, the Task equivelent would be `Task<T[]>.ToObservable().Concat();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting an `Observable<T[]>` is because `ToObservable` on a `Task<T>` returns `Observable<T>`. It must do this to ensure any type of Task can be converted to an `Observable`. In this case, a Task is used to represent an asynchronous function which returns a single value. An Observable is used to represent an asynchronous function with *multiple* values. So, when we convert a Task to an Observable, we convert an asynchronous function which *can only* return a single value -> an asynchronous function which *will only* return a single value.

Therefore, once we have an asynchronous function which returns only one value, and that value is an object which can *contain* multiple values, we must create another asynchronous function which returns all values contained in the object. To do so, we can use `SelectMany`.

```
Task<T[]> taskOfCollection = ...;

Observable<T[]> obsOfCollection = TaskOfCollection.ToObservable();

Observable<T> obsOfItems = obsOfCollection.SelectMany(x => x.ToObservable());
```

However, since `x` is an array, it is `Enumerable`, and `SelectMany` knows how to handle `Enumerable`, so we can just return `x`.

```
Observable<T> obsOfItems = obsOfCollection.SelectMany(x => x);
```

The above is simply a long-winded way of doing a `Merge`.

```
Observable<T> obsOfItems = obsOfCollection.Merge();
```

And, since there is only one item returned from the obsOfCollection, `Concat` works too (`Concat` just means "Merge on thing at a time".)

```
Observable<T> obsOfItems = obsOfCollection.Concat();
```

So, your final expression becomes:

```
Observable<T> obs = task.ToObservable().Merge();
// or
Observable<T> obs = task.ToObservable().Merge(1);
// or
Observable<T> obs = task.ToObservable().Concat();
```

## Reason:

The ***reason*** `ToObservable` on a `Task<T[]>` does not return an `Observable<T>`, is because there is no overload to do so. However, the reason there is no overload, is because it would then prevent users from using an `Observable` to `await` an array of things.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should be simple enough if you look at the `ToObservable` extension method for converting a task to an observable.

It looks like this:

```
IObservable<TResult> ToObservable<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task)
```

So if you start with a `Task<T[]>` then you're going to get an `IObservable<T[]>` out.

So, for example, this holds:

```
Task<int[]> task = Task.Run(() => new [] { 1, 2, 3 });

IObservable<int[]> observable = task.ToObservable();
```

Now if you want to get an `IObservable<int>` out then you need to do this:

```
IObservable<int> observable2 = observable.SelectMany(x => x);
```